# Running the service with Kafka and GCP SDK in Alpine docker image

Tags: .net, docker, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, alpine-linux

I have .NET service that is using Kafka client and GCP SDK. Also I may have separate services that are using Kafka or GCP SDK.

The main issue is that I'm running the service in the Docker Alpine image (3.10):

1. GCP SDK is using gRPC library. It [does not work](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18428#issuecomment-535041155) with musl libc library that is the default for Alpine. In order to use this library it is necessary to install a compatibility lib as it is stated in the link I provided. Once the workaround is applied it replaces musl libc with glibc. This works for gRPC and GCP
2. Kafka is using `librdkafka.so` library. It works fin in Alpine with musl. But it [does not work](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1423#issuecomment-704264330) in Alpine with glibc

So at the end I have a quite frequent Alpine distro, that is running 2 very frequent libs - Kafka nad GCP. But they are absolutely incompatible...

Is that possible in some wy to use both musl and glibc?

***UPDATE***
The current solution was to migrate to debian based image

Comment: Switching to a Debian or Ubuntu base image is probably easier than working around Alpine's limitations here, especially if you're working around it by adding a bunch of extra libraries.

Comment: I'm waiting for some Christmas miracle :)